# Need help with HTML/CSS/jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout

I have an image that looks like this. And I want to put it on my site BUT I DON'T want it to be an image. I only want the image part of it to be an image, and all the other images/text that you see below should be 'added' onto the main background image using html/css. BUT I am having extreme difficulty understanding how to do it!! :( I've read 6 tutorials, and just don't get it.

Main BG image:

[image]

and here's what it should look like, once I've added images and text to it using HTML/CSS. But this is what I can't figure out how to do. I just don't understand how to place everything on it where I want them to be!:

[image]

Please help, any help at all is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a background image on a containing element.  Here is a quick example using your image as a background: http://jsfiddle.net/q8QJv/1/

Comment: wow! thats awesome thank you so much!!!!! I see one thing that I don't understand... How does the CSS know which image it is referring to, when on the left in the html, there is no class/name/id attribute set for the image?

Comment: On the left the div is `<div id="background">`.  On the right there is a css file in which there is a rule setting the background image. `#background {}`

Comment: Thank you so much! You literally saved me from losing my job! I can't thank you enough, thanks to that link you sent me, I now understand how it works. Thank yyoooooouuuuuuuuuuu!!!! :-D

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `div` and set its [`background-image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-image) CSS property to be that image.

You're going to need to do a bunch of work to make everything else line up properly within it, but it should be manageable.

I would recommend that you use `em`s as your length unit, as opposed to pixels, in case users scale your page... it should help keep things lined up at most normal scales.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please also recommend a very easy to follow tutorial for idiots like me about how to line things up? :)

Comment: A good website that covers this in detail is nettuts.com they have recently done a good series of screencasts, which cover ways of achieving effects simmilar to this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-builds/convert-a-warm-cheerful-web-design-to-html-and-css/

Answer (score 1):

You can feasibly avoid using your image at all here using CSS `border-radius`.

Three of the corners will be dead easy to do using `border-radius`.

The fourth corner is more tricky. `border-radius` is flexible enough that you should be able to achieve the effect you've designed using it, or at least something close.

Something like the following:

```
.mybox {
  -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 20px;
}
```

Even more complex shapes are possible. However with odd shapes like that it can get a bit tricky to make `border-radius` work consistently between various browsers. It also obviously won't do the button you're putting in the corner.

For this reason, I'd suggest using a simple `border-radius` style to make all the corners rounded in the same way, and then place a single image layered on top of it in the bottom left corner do to your special corner.

Of course, you can stick with the image you have, in which case others have already suggested workable solutions, so I won't repeat them here. But hopefully you'll consider the border-radius option as an alternative.

Here's a page with a good overview of some border-radius tricks (and some other fun CSS stuff): http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/border-radius/

One *big* caveat to all this is that `border-radius` doesn't work in Internet Explorer. The good news though is that there is an excellent work-around for this in the shape of [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/).

Comment: "One big caveat to all this is that border-radius doesn't work in Internet Explorer."  That should be moved to the top of the answer.  ;)  +1 for suggesting a css solution, though.

Comment: @Stephen - the CSS3Pie work-around pretty much solves the IE problem.

Comment: I think the CSS3Pie project is freaking cool.  However, IE doesn't handle `.htc` files well.  It tries to fetch the `.htc` file on *every* element that uses it, so if you have a very heavily styled CSS3 design, performance can be hindered in IE.

Comment: Actually the server can be configured to force the file to be cached, but then IE *re-parses the script for every element anyway*!

Comment: @Stephen - performance-smormance; IE users are used to things going slowly. ;) Yeah, that was a joke! But seriously, I've seen sites with a whole stack of elements using CSS3Pie, and they've always been perfectly snappy. It's not ideal, but then nor is loading a whole bunch of differently coloured corner graphics to do the same thing, which is the only realistic alternative in IE. Compared to that, PIE is actually a breath of fresh air.

Comment: I'm interested enough that I'm going to spin up CSS3Pie on the next project that I have with CSS3 requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need some markup like:

```
<div id="container">
<header>
<h2>text title</h2>
<img src="top_right_image.png"/>
</header>
<p>Main body text</p>
<footer>
<a href="clickable location"><img src="clickable image" /></a>
</footer>
</div>
```

You can then style away using:

background-image for the "container" div.
You can sent the location absolutely for the heading, right image, body text and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could have a container div that would be centered, set the `background-image` to point to your bg image, set the proper amount of `padding` and would contain all other elements. It could have a `relative position`. Text title looks like an `h1` to me. Top right image would be an image floated to the right. Your paragraph would be inside a `p`. Clickable image could have an absolute position with `left` and `bottom` set to the proper amount.

Something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>text title</h1>
    <img src="/someImage" alt="" />
    <p>a paragraph</p>
    <a href="/aLink">clickable button</a>
</div>
```

[Fiddle demo with css applied](http://jsfiddle.net/rfvgyhn/jLpny/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="boxWrap">
    <div class="boxHead">
        <h2>Some text here <img src="logo.png" /></h2>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    <div class="clickable"><a href="#"><img src="triangleImg.png" /></a></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.boxWrap {
    min-width: 50%;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.boxWrap .boxHead {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
}

.boxHead h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.boxHead img {
    float: right;
}

.boxWrap p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.boxWrap .clickable {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 0 0 1em 0;

}

.boxWrap .clickable img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uypqp/2/).

I've not substituted in any real images for either the logo (in the `h2` element), or the bottom left corner. But this should be easily adaptable for your needs, obviously if you need any help adapting this, or need explanation of what I've done (or *why*), leave comments and I'll do my best to help as I can.